# How to reference a DataFrame cell based upon another key

Tags: python, dataframe, element

how would I access the age cell corresponding to another key.  Something similar to a vlookup in excel.

Given that I have the following Dataframe

```
df_links2 = pd.DataFrame({'Link': ['http:\\link1',
                                   'http:\\link2',
                                   'http:\\link3',
                                   'http:\\link4',
                                   'http:\\link5',
                                   'http:\\link6',
                                   'http:\\link7',
                                   'http:\\link8',
                                   'http:\\link9',
                                   'http:\\link10'],
                          'Ages': ['U10', 'U11', 'U12', 'U13', 'U14', 'U15', 'U16', 'U17', 'U18', 'U19'],
                          'Gender': ['female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male']
                          })
```

I've tried to pull out the corresponding cell in Ages: that correspond to the http:\link9

Is there a way to reference a corresponding key element based of another?

I basically want to loop over all of my links above but within the function process_table_into_DataFrame I want to be able to pass in the values of age and gender that correspond to the link that I've iterated on.

```
for link in df_links2.Link:
    driver.get(link)
    table = create_table_from_link(driver)
    age = df_links2.get("Age").Link[link]  <------- error below

    df_new = process_table_into_DataFrame(table, age=age, gender=gender)


Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Link'
  File "C:\app.py", line 148, in <module>
    age = df_links2.get("Age").Link[link]
```

Comment: What do you expect with this line ? age = df_links2.get("Age").Link[link]

Comment: If I were on iteration link4 then I would expect to get 'U13'

Answer (score 1):

I was checking on another page and ended up writing things as such...

```
for row in df_links2.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):

    driver.get(getattr(row,"Link"))

    table = create_table_from_link(driver)

    age = getattr(row,"Age")
    gender = getattr(row,"Gender") 
    df_new = process_table_into_DataFrame(table, age=age, gender=gender)

If anyone can explain why this works it would be appreciated as I'd like to know why a dart tossed in the dark hit something :)
```

Answer (score 0):

So try something like this.

```py
for row in df_links2.iterrows():
    info = row[1]
    driver.get(info.Link)
    table = create_table_from_link(driver)
    age = info.Ages
    gender = info.Gender

    df_new = process_table_into_DataFrame(table, age=age, gender=gender)
```